# GPS coordinates on mobile phones

Tags: iphone, android, gps, coordinates

Can GPS on a phone, such as iPhone or Android determine your Z coordinates ?

I know it certainly has to be able to determine X and Y, well longitude, latitude that is, but what about the Z coordinates ? Can it determine your height, and can I obtain height relative to ground ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height, as measured by a gps, is relative to the [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) ellipsoid. The WGS84 is representative of the field where the gravity is the same, the geoid. Not quite the same as the ground.

Comment: Not entirely true - WGS84, as you say, is an ellipsoid - it is also a 3D reference datum, and as such constitutes a vertical reference datum. But that reference datum is still an ellipsoid, NOT the geoid, which, as you also correctly say, is a gravitational iso-surface, and therefore not an ellipsoid (it's very irregular, especially around mountain ranges). The EGM96 geoid is defined in terms of the WGS 84 ellipsoid, but is an empirically measured data set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid

Answer (score 0):

You can determine altitude with iPhone using CoreLocation
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Android surely can ... have a look at the features of e.g. [MyTracks](http://mytracks.appspot.com/features) which include even evaluation profiles.

Altitude, however, is usually measured in "above sealevel", which means, that you could determine the distance from the ground by substracting the ground evaluation from your actual evaluation: ev(ground) - alt = distance(fromGround).